# Why there is no `new` operator when creating generator iterator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, generator

I am reading this article https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators and I read  words

> That's a little strange to wrap your head around. You also may be tempted to wonder, why isn't it var it = new foo(). Shrugs. The whys behind the syntax are complicated and beyond our scope of discussion here.

I am very interested why there is no `new` operator to create generator iterator? It reminds me creating an object by using a factory or Python construction.

Example from the source page:

```
function *foo() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
    yield 4;
    yield 5;
}
var it = foo();
```

Comment: Just a heads up, use > to do a quote (see my edit). Backticks mess with whitespace.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thx :)

Comment: Np. Posting a truncated version of the function it references may be helpful too for context. Questions shouldn't rely on external material to make sense. If the link goes down, it'll hurt your question.

Comment: It reminds you of creating an object but it reminds me of creating a closure - in which case needing a `new` would feel very strange.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more confusing if it was called with `new`? What would `this` refer to inside the generator? What exactly would it mean for a generator function to look like a constructor function, but not actually being invoked during construction (or only partially)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually in the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generator-objects)

> Generator Function objects are constructor functions...
>   A Generator object is an instance of a generator function..

Whenever you call a generator, the generator returns a new instance, because it is a constructor function.
There's no need for `new`, as it always does the same as a regular function called with `new`, it returns a new instance of the generator, meaning calling it with `new` would be superfluous.

```js
function *foo() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
    yield 4;
    yield 5;
}

function bar() {}

var it = foo();
var to = new bar();
var te = bar();


console.log( it, it instanceof foo ); // generator, true
console.log( to, to instanceof bar ); // function, true
console.log( te, te instanceof bar ); // undefined, false
```

In the above example we can see that calling the `foo()` generator function returns a new instance of the generator, much the same way as calling the regular `bar()` method with `new` does.
Calling `bar()` as a regular function does however not return an instance, but just `undefined`, or the return value, if such a value is set.

Here's an overview from the specification on how it's all related

[image]